# How do you vertically concatenate two Polars data frames in Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-polars

According to the Polars documentation, in Python, you can vertically concatenate two data frames using the procedure shown in the below code snippet:

```py
df_v1 = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [1],
        "b": [3],
    }
)
df_v2 = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [2],
        "b": [4],
    }
)
df_vertical_concat = pl.concat(
    [
        df_v1,
        df_v2,
    ],
    how="vertical",
)
print(df_vertical_concat)
```

The output of the above code is:

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 3   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 4   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

How do you perform the same operation in Rust?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as follows:

```rust
let df_vertical_concat = df_v1.vstack(&df_v2).unwrap();
```

Comment: If using the Lazy API, it becomes [`concat(&[my, lazy, frames], should_rechunk)?`](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/fn.concat.html)

Comment: And now `concat()` has a third argument, `parallel: bool`